# Git Authorizations - Per Repository Permissions

Tags: git

I have a private SVN server on a VPS for my small business. I can define permissions per project basis. That aids me a lot since I don't want my freelancers to access all the projects we develop.

I planned to move to GIT. Install git on a server to Host repositories.

I did some research then realized that GIT lacks of permissions system.
I have an ssh key based authentication option which grants everyone to all my repositories.

Is there any practical way to add such an authorization mechanism to my server. to maintain origin repositories.

Or SVN is still a better approach?

Comment: Try [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/gitlab-ce/), they have an excellent permission system. The whole software is similar to GitHub. Packages are available [here](https://www.gitlab.com/downloads/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, Git has no native authorization system.

In order to use Git in an enterprise context, you should (must) use one of several repository systems which build on Git.

some options:

[GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/gitlab-ce/), as pointed out by mnme is very versatile and user friendly, but it comes with a lot of server dependencies. It also has a very useful commericial version.

Another alternative is [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/), which also has a strong permission system.

My favorite is [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/), which has really useful, finegranular permissions (on branchlevel, if you want) and includes a useful review system (which you don't have to use).

There are also a couple of commercial products available.

So, play it safe, use a repository server!