# Git Permissions per repo http

Tags: git

I have implemented a private git server over http using the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) and added a few user.

I would like to implement per repo permissions to the users, there are some [questions from over 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135616/git-authorizations-per-repository-permissions) years ago that says it is not possible and to use github,gitlab,etc. Is it still the case?

Or do i need to use other tools like [Gitosis](https://github.com/tv42/gitosis) or [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)?

Comment: "Yes" on all questions. Nothing is changed. Hint: GitLab-on-premise is the most advanced solution but also very heavy. [There are many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246093/7976758) simpler, lighter tools.

Comment: @phd I am very late but could you post your comment as an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Yes" on all questions. Nothing is changed. Hint: [GitLab-on-premise](https://about.gitlab.com/install/) is the most advanced solution but also very heavy. There are many simpler, lighter tools.

Let me copy my old answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44246093/7976758 :

1. You can do ssh + [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html). No web interface, just pure git. For web interface use [gitweb](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/gitweb) or [cgit](http://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/).
2. Or [Klaus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/klaus) — a WSGI server with both web interface and git smart HTTP transport.
3. [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/).
4. [pagure](https://pagure.io/)
5. http://gitprep.yukikimoto.com/
6. https://gogs.io/
7. https://gitbucket.github.io/gitbucket-news/about/
8. https://rocketgit.com/